# Excel VBA - Pause Events while Updating ComboBox

Tags: events, excel, userform, vba

I have an application written in VBA for Excel that takes in a live data feed. Whenever there is a change in the data, various events are triggered within VBA.

I also have some UserForms with ComboBoxes on them. My problem is that when I click the down arrow on the ComboBox and try to make a selection, the moment I get an update from the data feed, the ComboBox resets. What I would like to do is pause the events while I am making my selection in the ComboBox and then unpause it when I am done. How do I generate this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can put a flag to bypass the update event on your combobox until a selection is made.

```
Private bLock as boolean  ' declare at module level

' When a user clicks on the combobox
Private Sub DropDownArrow_Click()  ' or cboComboBox_Click()
    bLocked = True
End Sub

' This procedure is the one that does the updating from the data source.
' If the flag is set, do not touch the comboboxes.
Private Sub subUpdateComboBoxes()
    If Not bLocked then
        ' Update the comboboxes
    End If
End Sub


' When the selection is made, or the focus changes from the combobox.
' check if a selection is made and reset the flag.
Private Sub cboComboBox_AfterUpdate()  ' Or LostFucus or something else
    if Format(cboComboBox.Value) <> vbNullString Then
        bLocked = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I was able to figure out what was causing the ComboBox to reset but I definitely like your solution because the act of clicking on the down arrow actually pauses the updates. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Try this to turn off:

> application.enableevents = false

And this to turn back on:

> application.enableevents = true

Comment: So, I'm assuming I would set Application.EnableEvents to false inside the DropDownArrow procedure in the ComboBox, but I don't want the Events to be re-enabled until after a selection has been made

Comment: It'd help to see some of your code to really know what is going on. The real question is why does the combobox reset? can you post the code?

Comment: I was able to find the issue. I had a function written to update the userform. Apparently that function also reset the ComboBox. By limiting calls to the function, I was able to resolve the issue. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

To pause and show a message and to keep working on something during the pause. finally press button

```
Public Ready As Boolean

Private Sub Command1_Click()
Ready = True
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
Me.Show
Ready = False
Call Wait
Label1.Visible = True
End Sub

Public Function Wait()
Do While Ready = False
    DoEvents
Loop
End Function
```